# Specific javascript code only working with alert statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

So I have a drop down menu that's supposed to be populated by a Json object value. The code reads like this:

```
$("#sport").val(model.SportId);
```

Well, when I load the page, it doesn't work. The drop down list defaults to the default "None Selected" option. So I do a ghetto debug and I put an alert on model.SportId to see what's up.

And when I refresh the page...it works. The only thing that I did was

```
alert(model.SportId);
```

It brings up a pop up window that says "1" and then the drop down menu value goes to the option 'Major League Baseball' (which is the text of that option value). That's it. That's the only thing I changed. Putting the alert before that first line of code. If I put the alert after the code, it doesn't work. I have no idea why this is.

The viewmodel that the Json object is derived from has SportId as a nullable int. Could that have anything to do with it?

Edit:

Okay, so in my razor view, this is the javascript I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var model=@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Title));
    var read=@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    var sportsurl='@Url.Action("GetSports", "Titles")';
    var sportsteamsurl='@Url.Action("GetSportsTeams", "Titles")';

    TitleBasicEdit(model, read, sportsurl, sportsteamsurl);
});
```

And the javascript function titlebasicedit is:

```
function TitleBasicEdit(model, url, read, backurl, seasonsurl, autocompleteurl, urlforward, sportsurl, sportsteamsurl) {
if ((model.TitleTypeId == 3) || (model.TitleTypeId == 8)) {
    GetSports(sportsurl);
    SportsDependency(sportsteamsurl);
    alert(model.SportId);
    $("#sport").val(model.SportId);
    $("#sport").change();
    $("#hometeam").val(model.HomeSportTeamId);
    $("#awayteam").val(model.AwaySportTeamId);
}
```

Comment: can you show more of your markup/js?

Comment: Do you have it in a `.ready` function?

Comment: Updated. And I do have it in a ready function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could be an issue related to an asynchronous task you perform while populating your options (like an ajax request). That could be the reason why the alert() works: it stops the execution oj javascript so that the task has enough time to be completed (anyway a link may be really appreciated).

edit: the GetSports() function could be that task;

Comment: This will be the issue.  Alerts alter js execution, allowing the async ajax call to finish so that when it returns, the ajax call has populated the controls, and your subsequent code can read the values.  You'll need to use a callback and execute the code after your alert in the callback function that is called when your ajax call returns.

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Forgot about the Asynchronous in AJAX.

Comment: @chad or if you use jquery 1.5+ you can also use $.Deferred objects (no more nested callbacks)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if it is because model.SportId is a typeof === 'number' ..? Have you tried this? I don't know why it would work though, because jQuery should be smart enough to handle this:

```
$("#sport").val(model.SportId+'');
```

Also, try this:

```
alert($("#sport").length);
$("#sport").val(model.SportId);
alert($("#sport").length);
```

It could be that your javascript is executing before the HTML loads. The alert() may give it just enough time to load.